# Error when training model with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1-Hm2rNkik&list=LL&index=2 to finetune. The only difference is that i'm using the GPT2Tokenizer and GPT2LMHeadModel instead of BERT.

When i get to the training part (11:53) i get the following error:

```
ValueError: `Checkpoint` was expecting model to be a trackable object (an object derived from `Trackable`), got GPT2LMHeadModel(
  (transformer): GPT2Model(
    (wte): Embedding(50257, 768)
    (wpe): Embedding(1024, 768)
    (drop): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    (h): ModuleList(
      (0-11): 12 x GPT2Block(
        (ln_1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): GPT2Attention(
          (c_attn): Conv1D()
          (c_proj): Conv1D()
          (attn_dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          (resid_dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
        (ln_2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): GPT2MLP(
          (c_fc): Conv1D()
          (c_proj): Conv1D()
          (act): NewGELUActivation()
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
    )
    (ln_f): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  )
  (lm_head): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=50257, bias=False)
). If you believe this object should be trackable (i.e. it is part of the TensorFlow Python API and manages state), please open an issue.
```

I'm not sure how to fix this? This is the training code i used from the video:

```py
training_args = TFTrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',          
    num_train_epochs=2,          
    per_device_train_batch_size=8, 
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16
    warmup_steps=500,               
    weight_decay=0.01,             
    logging_dir='./logs',           
    logging_steps=10,
)


with training_args.strategy.scope():
#     model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2")

trainer = TFTrainer(
    model=model,                       
    args=training_args,                 
    train_dataset=train_dataset,       
    eval_dataset=test_dataset       
)

trainer.train()
```

Comment: You are loading a pytorch model but use the tensorflow trainer. Use [TFGPT2LMHeadModel](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/gpt2#transformers.TFGPT2LMHeadModel) instead.

Comment: @cronoik   TFGPT2LMHeadModel got rid of the error but it introduced a new one: "TypeError: Expected string passed to parameter 'y' of op 'NotEqual', got -100 of type 'int' instead. Error: Expected string, but got -100 of type 'int'" 
do you know about this?